# Can I directly use an oscilloscope's FFT function for EMI measurement?

Tags: oscilloscope, emc, receiver, fft, spectrum-analyzer

The latest oscilloscopes with FFT and real-time functions are very useful for EMI debugging with a near-field probe, but why can't we just use them for the far-field EMI scan? EMI receivers are much more expensive.

Comment: Depends on your requirements.  Pre-compliance sanity check?

Comment: The dynamic range isn't very high, and aliasing may obscure the results, depending on sample rate and band of interest. You also may not get a choice of average/peak/quasi-peak (though I don't know what all options are offered by scopes these days, maybe some do; anyway, peak and average are usually sufficient for pre-comp purposes).